# javax.ejb.NoSuchEJBException: Could not find stateful bean: 3j011-udy7sm-hkt798pd-1-hkt7bobh-9

Tags: ejb, stateful-session-bean

Many times whenever I try to access some pages or click buttons "Could not find stateful bean: 3j011-udy7sm-hkt798pd-1-hkt7bobh-9"error hits on the screen for the JSF project.Do anybody know the cause for this errpr

Comment: so you mean it is working sometimes but not always? please specify more information, what app server or what framework you are using? and from where you are invoking the bean?

Comment: Possibly your stateful session bean was unused too long. But that's just a guess, please add application server, timeouts, and the source to your question.

Comment: @Amir Noori The application server is Jboss and we are using jsf framework,and jpa which manages the relational data to a application

Comment: @shree18 I think "3j011-udy7sm-hkt798pd-1-hkt7bobh-9" is just a name that JBoss use for its own sake. and you did not answer my question that is this working sometimes(like one out of ten times) or not? also tell us what is your application package structure, give us some code, and are invoker of EJB and EJB itself on the same machine,...?

Comment: @AmirNoori,Anyhow thanks for your effort,the problem was connected with the sessions.(Berylium was right,it was session time out issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you ran into a timeout, and the stateful session been has been removed by the container.

You can use `@StatefulTimeout` (EJB 3.1) to set this value. A quote from the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ejb/StatefulTimeout.html):

> Specifies the amount of time a stateful session bean can be idle (not receive any client invocations) before it is eligible for removal by the container.

To verify if that is really the case, add a method with `@PreDestroy`, so you can see if the SFSB has been removed.

Example:

```java
@Stateful(name = "xxx")
@StatefulTimeout(value = 15, unit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
public class Sfsb {
  @PreDestroy
  public void preDestroy() {
    System.out.println("INFO: " + "@PreDestroy");
  }
}
```